# Google function not able to use service account from oauth2client

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api

I am using the following code in my windows which works but as soon as I deploy it as cloud function on GCP I get this error? How do I get around it? What I am trying to do is read a google sheet and use it in my function.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
  credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

    delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject(EMAIL_FROM)
```

the google function logs give the following error

textPayload: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client'"
ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth

How do I resolve it?

Comment: What's your `requirements.txt` file? Are you running your code in a virtual env locally?

Comment: This is what I have in the requirement.txthttplib2==0.15.0
firebase_admin==3.2.1
oauth2client==4.1.3
google_api_python_client==1.8.0
protobuf==3.11.3  I am running from google cloud functions

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your dependency `oauth2client`, it is deprecated as mentioned [here](https://pypi.org/project/oauth2client/)

You can prefer `google-auth==1.13.1` and it should work

So, your next question will be: why it works on my local environment? I think you have installed google-auth globally and your code take this dependency even if it's not in the `requirements.txt`. I recommend you to work with virtual environment and to install the dependencies only in this venv.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, by the way target audience is the url that you want to access.

```
import argparse
import google.auth
import google.auth.app_engine
import google.auth.compute_engine.credentials
import google.auth.iam
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import google.oauth2.credentials
from google.oauth2 import service_account

class AuthenticationConstants:
    AUTHENTICATION_SCOPES_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
    OAUTH_TOKEN_URI = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'

class JWT(object):
    def __init__(self, service_account_key_path):
        self.service_account_key_path = service_account_key_path
        self.credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            self.service_account_key_path)
        self.scoped_credentials = self.credentials.with_scopes(
            [AuthenticationConstants.OAUTH_TOKEN_URI])

    def get_google_open_id_connect_token(self, target_audience):
        signer_email = self.scoped_credentials.service_account_email
        signer = self.scoped_credentials.signer

        service_account_credentials = google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials(
            signer,
            signer_email,
            token_uri=AuthenticationConstants.OAUTH_TOKEN_URI,
            additional_claims={
                'target_audience': target_audience
            }
        )

        service_account_jwt = service_account_credentials._make_authorization_grant_assertion()
        request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
        body = {
            'assertion': service_account_jwt,
            'grant_type': google.oauth2._client._JWT_GRANT_TYPE,
        }
        token_response = google.oauth2._client._token_endpoint_request(
            request, AuthenticationConstants.OAUTH_TOKEN_URI, body)
        return token_response['id_token']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--service-account-path")
    parser.add_argument("--target-audience")
    result = parser.parse_args()
    jwt = JWT(result.service_account_path)
    print(jwt.get_google_open_id_connect_token(result.target_audience))
```

The following is the requirements.txt that I use:

```
google-api-python-client==1.7.11
```